# == Noob Here == I'm Trying to Build LineageOS 16.0 from source for Samsung Galaxy Fame Lite (nevisvess) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source, samsung-galaxy, lineageos

> NOTE: **this is an unsupported device**, the repos: ***device***, ***kernel***, ***vendor***, ***bcm-common*** are made for **cm11**, i'm trying to port from `cm` to `lineage` renaming some values (example: `cm_nevisvess` ==> `lineage_nevisvess`)

the error will be generated after `brunch nevisvess`:

```
alessandro_privitera@VMware:~/android/lineage$ source build/envsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/uml/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/nevisvess/vendorsetup.sh
including vendor/lineage/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
alessandro_privitera@VMware:~/android/lineage$ make clean && make clobber
14:23:31 Entire build directory removed.

#### build completed successfully (3 seconds) ####

14:23:42 Entire build directory removed.

#### build completed successfully (11 seconds) ####

alessandro_privitera@VMware:~/android/lineage$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. aosp_car_arm-userdebug
     8. aosp_car_arm64-userdebug
     9. aosp_car_x86-userdebug
     10. aosp_car_x86_64-userdebug
     11. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     12. m_e_arm-userdebug
     13. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     14. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     15. uml-userdebug
     16. lineage_nevisvess-userdebug
     17. lineage_arm-userdebug
     18. lineage_arm64-userdebug
     19. lineage_x86-userdebug
     20. lineage_x86_64-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 16
Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
LINEAGE_VERSION=16.0-20230612-UNOFFICIAL-nevisvess
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_nevisvess
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.19.0-43-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.2-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ3A.190801.002
OUT_DIR=/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out
RECOVERY_VARIANT=twrp
============================================
alessandro_privitera@VMware:~/android/lineage$ brunch nevisvess
including vendor/lineage/vendorsetup.sh
Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
LINEAGE_VERSION=16.0-20230612-UNOFFICIAL-nevisvess
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_nevisvess
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.19.0-43-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.2-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ3A.190801.002
OUT_DIR=/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out
RECOVERY_VARIANT=twrp
============================================
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
LINEAGE_VERSION=16.0-20230612-UNOFFICIAL-nevisvess
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_nevisvess
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.19.0-43-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.2-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ3A.190801.002
OUT_DIR=/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out
RECOVERY_VARIANT=twrp
============================================
[1/1] /home/alessandro_privitera/andro...neage/out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
[61/62] glob prebuilts/ndk/stl.bp
[80/80] /home/alessandro_privitera/and.../android/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja
/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/build-lineage_nevisvess-cleanspec.ninja is missing, regenerating...
/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/build-lineage_nevisvess.ninja is missing, regenerating...
[622/1034] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:23: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_UNION is no longer required - all files found in BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS are implicitly unioned; please remove from your BoardConfig.mk or other .mk file.
[1034/1034] including vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices/Android.mk ...
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:107: warning: ***************************************************************
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:108: warning: * Using prebuilt kernel binary instead of source              *
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:109: warning: * THIS IS DEPRECATED, AND WILL BE DISCONTINUED                *
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:110: warning: * Please configure your device to download the kernel         *
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:111: warning: * source repository to 
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:112: warning: * for more information                                        *
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:113: warning: ***************************************************************
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/etc/apns-conf.xml'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/etc/apns-conf.xml'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/etc/permissions/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/etc/permissions/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/bin/atrace'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/bin/atrace'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/lib/libasound.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/system/lib/libasound.so'
vendor/lineage/build/tasks/kernel.mk:297: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/kernel'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/kernel'
[ 99% 1040/1041] glob vendor/samsung/nevisvess/overlay/**/*
ninja: error: '/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaudiopolicy_legacy_intermediates/export_includes', needed by '/home/alessandro_privitera/android/lineage/out/target/product/nevisvess/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/audio.policy.rhea_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
14:30:25 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:19 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Repos for `nevisvess`:

Device: https://github.com/h2aroon/android_device_samsung_nevisvess

Kernel: https://github.com/h2aroon/android_kernel_samsung_nevisvess

Vendor: https://github.com/h2aroon/android_vendor_samsung_nevisvess

bcm-common: https://github.com/h2aroon/device_samsung_bcm-common

**Any help will be appreciated ;)**

"*i tried to see if there are the missing libraries i needed to install and i also desperately tried to ask ChatGPT :')*"